# How do i add a commands where it unban an user id from all the servers the bot is in

Tags: discord, discord.js

So i have tried this but it says "ReferenceError: member is not defined", can you guys help me fixing it please, i already have a command to ban someone from all the servers the bot is in but i don't know how to do for unban-all, so here is my code so you can guys take a look, i'm pretty new in discord.js so sorry if my code looks bad

````
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

/**
 * 
 * @param {import('discord.js').Client} client 
 * @param {import('discord.js').Message} message 
 * @param {string} args 
 * 
 */

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const targetID = args[0];
    const reason = args.slice(0).join(' ')

    const dm_messagev2 = new MessageEmbed()
    
    .setColor("#02fa49")

    .setTitle(":no_entry: BAN :no_entry:")

    .addField("**Message :**", `${member.user.tag} Vous avez été déban-all de Storm-Community.`)

    .addField("**Raison : **", `${reason || 'Aucune raison définie.'}`)

    .addField("**Autheur : **", `${message.author.username}.`)

    .setFooter("Bot by Roka | 1.1")

    member.send({ embeds: [dm_messagev2]})

    setTimeout(function(){
        client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.unban(targetID)).then(() => {
            const embedv3 = new MessageEmbed()
    
                .setColor("#02fa49")
    
                .setTitle(":white_check_mark: Succès")
    
                .addField("**Message :**", `${member.user.tag} as été déban-all de la communauté.`)
    
                .addField("**Raison : **", `${reason || 'Aucune raison définie.'}`)
    
                .addField("**Auteur : **", `${message.author.username}.`)
    
                .setFooter("Bot by Roka | 1.1")

                message.channel.send({ embeds: [embedv3]});
        });
    }, 2000); 

       /* const dmembed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("You have been banned from all the servers i am in")
        .setDescription('Your Crime was `${reason}`. If you want to apeal, You may join [Appeal Server by Clicking here](https://discord.gg/ZWWYy37atN)')
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        message.targetID.send(embed)*/
};

exports.info = {
    name: 'unbanall', // Command name
    description: 'Clears a specific amount of messages in a channel', // Command description
    category: 'mod',
    icon: '',
    usage: '<count>' // Command usage
};

exports.config = {
    args: true, // Whether this command should require one or more arguments
    guildOnly: true, // Whether the command should be used in a guild or not
    permissions: {
        user: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'], // Required guild permissions for the user to use this command (must be a valid permission flag)
        bot: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'], // Required guild permissions for the bot to run this command (must be a valid permission flag)
    },
    aliases: ['uball', 'unban-all', 'débanall', 'déban-all', 'deban-all', 'debanall'], // Aliases
    disabled: false, // Whether this command is disabled or not
};```
````

Comment: I don't see a definition of `member` anywhere in the code. maybe that's why it says member is not defined.

Comment: I am not an expert in Discord.js so I'll leave it to someone who knows more to solve this.

Comment: use guild.unban as the user is banned so they can't be a member considering the bot can not see them, only able to get user information from someone who isn't banned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your Reference Error is coming from

```
member.send({ embeds: [dm_messagev2]})
```

I'm not quite sure why you need this for an unban as it seems to be a notice of a ban. Assuming its just leftover code...

As for unbanning all your banned members, you can access these bans through this method!

```
guild.bans.fetch();
```